# Loop for input section of rename script

Tags: beginner, bash, linux

For the input section of a script, I wrote a snippet using a `while` loop and an `if` statement to check whether there are matches for the `$search`. Only if there are matches does it move on to the input of `$replace`; if there are no matches it asks for `$search` again.

```
 while true; do
     echo "Please enter token to be replaced: "
     read -e -r search
     match="$(find . -maxdepth 1 -path "*${search}*" -printf "." | wc -c)"
     if [ "${match}" -gt 0 ]; then
         echo "${match} file(s) found"
         break
     else
         echo "no matches found!"
         echo
     fi
 done

 echo "Please enter replacement: "
 read -e -r replace

# I used the following command to check if the output was right
# echo "rename 's/$search/$replace/g' ./*"
```

In this snippet I used advice I got from [a question I asked on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/q/45405034).

This code is going to be used as the input section of a rename script. In the last line I added an `echo "rename...` command to check if the output works as expected.

The script is meant to process all files matching the `$search` criteria in the current directory. Therefore I used `find . -maxdepth 1...`.

The script of which this snippet is part of [got reviewed here earlier](/q/171515).

Does this code match general standards?

Comment: `-path` uses a shell pattern, while `s///` uses a regular expression. Therefore, if you search for `a.c`, file `abc` won't be found by `find`, even though `rename` would match and rename it. Similarly, `a?c` would find `abc`, but replace won't match it.

Comment: Are you defining a function or a script?  There's no sign that this code is turned into a shell function.  Did you leave out code?

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty new to programming, _function_ was not the right term I guess. I'm writing a _script_. I change this in the question...

Comment: @choroba I tried to go this way: `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype sed -regex "*${search}*" -printf "." | wc -c` but I did not get it to work. Also I wasn't sure witch `regextype` to choose, I thought `sed` was the closest to `rename`, but please correct me...

Comment: `rename` uses perl regexes which might be unsupported by `find`.

Comment: @choroba I thought `sed` uses perl regexes too, that's why I tried the above. As you can see on [my post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405034/bash-alternative-for-ls-grep) I tried to find a proper way to not use `ls | grep "$search"` but also not to use `find`. I did not find anything, maybe because I did not ask clear enough. So maybe I go back to my `ls | grep` pipe or find a way to get `find` do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match by the same pattern as `rename`,
then it's probably best to use `perl`.
To be really pedantic and support filenames with embedded newlines,
you could use `-print0` of `find`,
and then in `perl` split the output by `\0` characters and filter with the `grep` function:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | perl -ne "print scalar grep /$search/, split /\0/"
```

Putting in your script:

```
 while true; do
     echo "Please enter token to be replaced: "
     read -e -r search
     match=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | perl -ne "print scalar grep /$search/, split /\0/")
     if [ "${match}" -gt 0 ]; then
         echo "${match} file(s) found"
         break
     else
         echo "no matches found!"
         echo
     fi
 done
```

Comment: **Thank you janos**, this works perfect! Looks like after all I kind of have to (at least a little) get into perl :-) AWESOME!